# Emiting an event once a client has connected or disconnected to server

Tags: python

I am new to python socket programming and i want to know if there is a networking framework i can use that can emit an event once a client has connected .For instance,once a client has connected,do something like run some code.This simple code i am using

```
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 7654                # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)
s.close                     # Close the socket when done
```

**Edit:**

Found asyncore http://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html#module-asyncore

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is fairly simple in sockets only

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 7654

s.bind((host,port)) #bind the host/port to the server
s.listen(1024) #put the server into listening mode

client, address = s.accept()
print "a client has connected "+str(address)
onConnect(client) #this function is fired when a client connects (and uses the client object as arg

while 1:
    data=client.recv(1024) #receives the data
    if data == None:
        break #breaks when empty data is being received (the client may have disconnected)
    print data #debug reasons

print "The client has disconnected "+str(address)

onDisconnect(client) #this function is fired when a client disconnects
```

You still have to create the onConnect and onDisconnect functions